# Workaround for call time pass by reference deprecation in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm upgrading a code base from PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.6.

I'm working through fixing occurrences of call-time pass by reference in my codebase, as documented on the PHP manual page http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php:

> Note: There is no reference sign on a function call - only on function
>   definitions. Function definitions alone are enough to correctly pass
>   the argument by reference. As of PHP 5.3.0, you will get a warning
>   saying that "call-time pass-by-reference" is deprecated when you use &
>   in foo(&$a);. And as of PHP 5.4.0, call-time pass-by-reference was
>   removed, so using it will raise a fatal error.

I have some functions like this:

```
function some_function($a, $b)
{
...
}
```

and this function is called sometimes like this:

```
some_function($a, $b);
```

and other times it's called using the now-deprecated call-time pass by reference feature:

```
some_function(&$a, &$a);
```

So I *cannot* update the function signature to this:

```
function some_function(&$a, &$b)
{
...
}
```

Since that would affect the callers that do not want to call it by reference.

So I tried creating a reference to the variables that should be passed by reference, and passing the reference:

For example, refactoring the calls from:

```
some_function(&$a, &$a);
```

To:

```
$refToA = &$a;
$refToB = &$b;
some_function($refToA, $refToB);
```

But the above didn't work, it seems PHP still makes a copy of them inside the function.

So just wondering if I have any other options, apart from having 2 versions of the function, one that takes it args by reference, and another which takes them by copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply call the function differently:

By Ref:

```
some_function( $a, $b );
```

By Value:

```
$copy_a = $a;
$copy_b = $b;
some_function( $copy_a, $copy_b );
```

and always use a by reference function. But when passing copies the function will not alter the real $a and $b.

```
function some_function( &$a, &$b )
{
    ...
}
```

Out of curiosity what does the function do that you sometimes want by ref and other times by value? It seems like it maybe **should** be 2 different functions.

Comment: I agree with the last sentence. One thing I thought was maybe the By Value code could be put in a wrapper function.

Comment: Haha. That's where I was going with my question. to do the automatic copy creation and still call the same ref function.

Comment: Exactly, could just be `some_function_by_value`, `some_function_by_ref`, or something that makes a little better sense to the actual use case.

Comment: You technically only need the by_value version added, but if you want to make it more clear to other devs why you created the wrapper, adding both isn't a bad idea.

Comment: Good point. I suppose it could also help you when you come back to the code a year later and wonder what the normal function does again :P.

Comment: Thanks @William_Wilson, can't upvote but answer accepted.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, identify the more common usage, say for example that is the one "by reference".

If so, refactor `some_function` to

```
function some_function(&$a, &$b) { ... }
```

Then add a new function

```
function some_function_byval($a, $b) { return some_function($a, $b); }
```

and change all the calls using "by value" function to use the new one.

The new function works simply because it will pass a reference to a copy of the parameters to the original function.